# StreamReader adds unwanted backslashes

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am reading a file that contains other file paths and i am putting it into a StringReader:

```
var inputReader = new StreamReader(input);
var reader = new StringReader(inputReader.ReadToEnd());
```

When i debug the StreamReader.ReadToEnd() and look at the whole text everything seems right. The paths have this form: **C:\\User\\ ....**

However when i now read each line in the file with:

```
string line = reader.ReadLine();
```

The paths have the following form: **C:\\\\User\\\\ ....**

Any suggestions on how to fix that? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Could we get a larger sample of the text being read. I've heard plenty of streamreader adding back slashes in debugger, but less this.

Comment: Looks like it's just escaping your backslashes. If you're viewing this in a debugging window of some kind, that's totally normal. If you're actually getting extra backslashes added to your value (for example, if you wrote that back out to a file) that would be incorrect, but would very much surprise me.

Comment: It really seems just to be the debugger. Thanks for the quick replies!